# Difference between secure and insecure cookies

Tags: android, session, cookies, session-cookies

I am developing an Android application where I have to maintain session. There are two websites that I need to log into.

For one website, when I get cookies from Cookie Store I get cookie.isSecure=true.

For other website, I get cookie.isSecure=false.

I would like to know what is the difference between Secure and Insecure cookies?

Would the browser behavior change with this value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A secure cookie instructs the browser that the cookie may only be sent to the server when connecting through SSL.

These are sites where the URL starts with https:// (note the s after http)

An insecure cookie will be sent to both http:// and https:// connections.

This mechanism ensures that session cookies (if set as secure) will always be encrypted in order to prevent eavesdropping.