# php apache unable to set cookie

Tags: php, apache, cookies

I am unable to successfully set a cookie on a new website on the same server that hosts other websites without this problem.

The entire file, no extra white-spaces before/after

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
setcookie("test", "Hello", time()+3600);
?>
```

I receive no feedback, error. Checked php/apache errors logs and nothing shown. Tried multiple browsers and the cookie is never set. No .htaccess, the apache virtual host is a copy of other sites that are working no special changes or anything. I am at a loss of what to check or how to debug from this point. Any ideas?

The response cookies from the network tab are being sent:

Here is a response header with path and domain on the setcookie

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 15 Jun 2018 20:46:23 GMT
Server: Apache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: test=Hello; expires=Fri, 15-Jun-2018 21:46:23 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=MYSITE.com;HttpOnly;Secure
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

here is the change without the path and domain
Set-Cookie: test=Hello; expires=Fri, 15-Jun-2018 21:50:47 GMT; Max-Age=3600;HttpOnly;Secure

Either way, looking at the cookies stored for the website it is still blank. And in code I can't access them on the second page refresh.

Comment: Do a network tab inspection. Check the headers returned by your request. See if cookie is there. Also add path parameter as "/" to make sure the cookie is accessible throughout your domain regardless of the path.

Comment: @jancha The response includes the cookie info i'll post it above. However looking at the site cookies they just don't exists still to the browser.

Comment: @jancha I also tried the "/" and adding in the domain name etc same results.

Comment: what makes you think that the cookie is not available? did you check resources tab in browser? can you see the cookie there? and how are you reading the cookies?

Comment: @jancha Yes, there are no cookies under storage -> cookies. I checked from the developer console and the browser cookie/privacy settings. I get the same results in firefox, chrome and edge. And from within PHP $_COOKIE is empty.

Comment: okay, it could be that because of your local timezone, the cookie is "expired" already, thus it's not set. +3600 adds 1h to GMT. check how that compares to your timezone.

Comment: @jancha Tried changing it to 360000, same results.

Comment: ok, another hint - it says "Secure", see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543866/difference-between-secure-and-insecure-cookies if you access the site over http: rather  than https, cookie is not set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary - it looks like you are setting a secure cookie, while accessing insecure site. Consider setting secure to false:

```
setcookie("test", "Hello", time()+3600, "/", null, false);
```

Comment: It looks like the server is not allowing unsecured cookies to be set it's ignoring the false. However that is a different issue at least I have a point to track down the other issues that come up now. The site doesn't have an ssl but accessing it through the invalid certificate https it somehow loaded a different website on the server, again another weird issue to track down but I can move forward. Thanks.

Comment: Its actually a shared IP and I didn't setup a 443 virtual host which is why it loaded a different site, just fyi if anyone else has that happen.